# Classify a region by its slope

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, matrix, classification

### Definitions

The **k<sup>th</sup>** ring of a square matrix of size **N**, where **1 ≤ k ≤ ceiling(N/2)** is the list formed by the elements of the **k<sup>th</sup>** and **(N-k+1)<sup>th</sup>** rows and columns, but without the first and last **k-1** elements.

Example:

```
Matrix:

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
8 7 6 5 4
3 2 1 9 8
7 6 5 4 3

Delimited in rings:

+-------------------+
| 1   2   3   4   5 |
|   +-----------+   |
| 6 | 7   8   9 | 1 |
|   |   +---+   |   |
| 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
|   |   +---+   |   |
| 3 | 2   1   9 | 8 |
|   +-----------+   |
| 7   6   5   4   3 |
+-------------------+
```

The first ring of the above is `1,2,3,4,5,1,4,8,3,4,5,6,7,3,8,6`, the second is `7,8,9,5,9,1,2,7` and the third is `6`.

An **N** by **N** matrix of positive integers is (for the purposes of this challenge):

- *concave* if all the integers on the **k<sup>th</sup>** ring are strictly greater than those on the **(k+1)<sup>th</sup>** ring, where **k** is any integer between **1** and **N**  (those on the first ring are greater than those on the second, which are in turn greater than those on the third etc.). Example:

  ```
  4 5 6 4 7   -> because 4,5,6,4,7,4,8,5,5,4,6,5,9,5,5,4 are all higher than
  4 3 2 2 4      any of 3,2,2,3,2,3,3,2, which are all higher than 1
  5 2 1 3 8
  5 3 3 2 5
  9 5 6 4 5
  ```
- *flat* if all the integers in the matrix are equal. Another example (perhaps redundant):

  ```
  2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2
  2 2 2 2
  ```
- *convex* if all the integers on the **k<sup>th</sup>** ring are strictly lower than those on the **(k+1)<sup>th</sup>** ring, where **k** is any integer between **1** and **N**  (those on the first ring are lower than those on the second, which are in turn lower than those on the third etc.). Example:

  ```
  1 2 1   -> because 1 and 2 are both lower than 6
  2 6 2
  1 2 1
  ```
- *mixed* if the matrix doesn't satisfy any of the above criteria. Example:

  ```
  3 3 3 3 3
  3 2 2 2 3
  3 2 3 2 3
  3 2 2 2 3
  3 3 3 3 3
  ```

### Challenge

Given **a square matrix** of positive integers of **size at least 3**, classify it according to the definitions above. That is, output one of four different *consistent* values based on whether the matrix is concave, flat, convex or mixed.

You can compete in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/59487) and can take input and provide output through any [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and in any reasonable format, while taking note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission (in bytes) for *every language* wins.

### Test cases

Here's a bunch of examples for you to choose from – I selected 6 from each category.

**Concave**

```
[[3, 3, 3], [3, 1, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[19, 34, 45], [34, 12, 14], [13, 13, 13]]
[[3, 4, 3, 4], [4, 2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 4, 3]]
[[4, 5, 6, 4, 7], [4, 3, 2, 2, 4], [5, 2, 1, 3, 8], [5, 3, 3, 2, 5], [9, 5, 6, 4, 5]]
[[7, 7, 7, 7, 7], [7, 6, 6, 6, 7], [7, 6, 5, 6, 7], [7, 6, 6, 6, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]
```

**Flat**

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
[[8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8], [8, 8, 8]]
[[120, 120, 120], [120, 120, 120], [120, 120, 120]]
[[10, 10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10, 10]]
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

**Convex**

```
[[1, 2, 1], [2, 6, 2], [1, 2, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[19, 34, 45], [34, 76, 14], [13, 6, 13]]
[[3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 4, 4, 3], [3, 4, 4, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
[[192, 19, 8, 6], [48, 324, 434, 29], [56, 292, 334, 8], [3, 4, 23, 23]]
[[291, 48, 7, 5], [47, 324, 454, 30], [58, 292, 374, 4], [9, 2, 53, 291]]
```

**Mixed**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 9], [6, 7, 8]]
[[10, 14, 21], [100, 8, 3], [29, 2, 19]]
[[5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 4, 4, 5], [5, 4, 6, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5]]
[[3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 2, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3]]
[[12, 14, 15, 16], [12, 18, 18, 16], [12, 11, 11, 16], [12, 14, 15, 16]]
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 4, 4, 4, 5], [5, 4, 6, 4, 5], [5, 4, 4, 4, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: This challenge has previously been posted in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16451/59487). Thanks to those who have given valuable feedback there.

Comment: Boy, wouldn't it be nice to have some **array-of-array string conversion to/from matrix** functions handy to process all those test cases in a variety of languages :)

Comment: @ngm Don't you dare think [we don't have one already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/129136/simplify-matrix-input)! :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18 17</s>  16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>I believe there is a lot of potential for this effort to be out-golfed</sup>

```
L‘HạŒỤṀ€IṠQṢ«FE$
```

A monadic link accepting a list of lists of numbers which returns a list of integers:

```
Concave ->  [0, 0]
Flat    ->  [-1, 0, 1]
Convex  ->  [-1, 0]
Mixed   ->  [-1, 0, 0]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUcMMj4e7Fh6d9HD3koc7Gx41rfF8uHNB4MOdiw6tdnNV@f//f3S0qY6CmY6CeayOAjZmLAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##tVSxTsQwDN3vKzLc2OHiJmnzASCQWJirjizofoDthJDYmZAQEiA2@IHCBuJDej9SbMdtmmvvJAak5M5x7Bf72e7lxXp91XVn2839Sfvx/HPXfr62zWZ7/X7aNk/nbfPy9XZ8tOy@b1HVNjdL/nvYbh5V11XVQqmqyjNFq84UiTqKrK0XKqsq4JOhC8s2jsQiU2WmvNhoj0YGrSz7o6TRTbOTJmTeYkxoERNFSJ7WrOjvxFhcUcQYHOuKaAHRxQ5wGKAo8t6Io/MjDCu4mE1ckp7r10hhdxWpxQgDcesskKw5Hs1cTMWBZFp0MSMGm5Ip56RmRCkErIj78MPPHFaIF52GzVZ/1wQoyyTFJSX4X11KNgjDwLUBIRsi2WkVYLYg044u3LijXdrQ6SAZadq5Uzpc2tPznmvIc2VQyIFc6E3wnC@lQYY56coIC9TWw5x6DJ/cC6HJFD2Upfe5ZrbsoQojE@PDaBCU11MqcxkzS9OOouMHynHnUCSBwtWKM2EfCMDaTzpDamhkBIeTm9R3H8Gj0Ibh3kMwhAA1fbtcGACUStlRo2VHTfSaae0kh0ka5oDFTt/Wvw).

`L‘H` could be replaced with the less efficient but *[atomically](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Atoms)* shorter `JÆm`.

#### How?

```
L‘HạŒỤṀ€IṠQṢ«FE$ - Link: list of (equal length) lists of numbers
L                - length
 ‘               - increment
  H              - halve
                 -   = middle 1-based index (in both dimensions as the input is square)
    ŒỤ           - sort multi-dimensional indices by their corresponding values
                 -   = a list of pairs of 1-based indexes
   ạ             - absolute difference (vectorises)
                 -   = list of [verticalDistanceToMiddle, horizontalDistanceToMiddle] pairs
      Ṁ€         - maximum of €ach
                 -   each = N/2-k (i.e. 0 as middle ring and N/2 as outermost)
        I        - incremental deltas (e.g. [3,2,2,3,1]->[3-2,2-2,3-2,1-3]=[-1,0,1,-2])
         Ṡ       - sign (mapping -n:-1; 0:0; and +n:1)
          Q      - de-duplicate
           Ṣ     - sort
                 -   = concave:[0, 1]; convex:[-1, 0]; flatOrMixed:[-1, 0, 1]
               $ - last two links as a monad
             F   -   flatten
              E  -   all equal? (1 if flat otherwise 0)
            «    - minimum (vectorises)
                 -   = concave:[0, 0]; convex:[-1, 0]; mixed:[-1, 0, 0]; flat:[-1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>219</s> <s>216</s> <s>189</s> 176 bytes

```python
def g(M):A=[sorted((M[1:]and M.pop(0))+M.pop()+[i.pop(j)for j in[0,-1]for i in M])for k in M[::2]];S={cmp(x[j],y[~j])for x,y in zip(A,A[1:])for j in[0,-1]};return len(S)<2and S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVRNj5swED2XX@FbQOuusPlmm0pRpd445WhxiDZsS7oLiNJV0qr966lncGLAJNkeGtnReHgznvGbmebQfa0rfjxuiyfyxc6cdLUU3@u2K7a2nQmW5ptqS7L7pm5s13Huesm5EyUKO@epbsmOlJVw6XuWw6mUJ5Ll@OUbyiJNeZ4/rJe/Hl8aey92OT2IP7sesqcHAP0sG3tFV3DjxOfvh7bofrQVeS4qe@184BDR@ti0ZdWRxae6ety8FgsLjDLwJIgQHiWwckpAZFpEbU4ton9CcNT7AAkQHYIYURJTkhholki4L/EB@pQSkw4YmjO4DbdhBjfoe6TIR4ExVJy@KbDhRCplhCF@jTSWa@Pg7FiGrxTeCYQRJwMfgXGDzFov9QzhaQ0UwVQxRgx85CRPrXc9XRldLD8uKBSaZaHKUjx@ft50ExIZ5sHwXU1xhkRYAJkRp@gYycUHmhENyrkLLPd/GMR1hWEP@vNG/L9rpk4DJEEvRfb/1b2NTNmUr8XepJMrDjnWCld08jk6x4zzG@SbPRmFw54ML7XkeFD4qu3mTpeGB0sguAQrB@eGLwWPgzHEwRN8R0gXgB7oYn0Bh8acmUiJTBMcRYoIPzo5DSAmrI8gPjmNfNX9Sd/m4DRhl8kas5WV@2I7S5anRkwAc1CKIQYUz9c3ZNOT5Lr4GmjN@5BYcqV@VaX5aiSdT6FRhbcpHAR@Hns3KeR9@Aymf9i3s5RitbWGqa012upqe44yNJL0ryDe0HvHvw)

Outputs `set([1]), set([0]), set([-1]),` or `False` for concave, flat, convex, or mixed, respectively.

Thx for: A whopping 27 bytes from a few optimizations by [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs). And then *another* 13 bytes afterwards.

The list comprehension `A` (due to ovs) creates a list of the elements of each ring, sorted.

Next, we compare the `max` and `min` values between adjacent rings by looking at the `0`th and `-1`th elements of each sorted list in A. Note that if, for example, `M` is concave, `min` of each outer ring must be greater than `max` of the next inner-most ring; and it then follows that `max` of each outer ring will also be greater than `min` of the next inner-most ring.

If `M` is concave, flat, or convex, the set of these `min/max` comparisons will have only 1 element from `{-1, 0, 1}`; if it is mixed, there will be two or more elements.

Comment: @ovs: That's pretty col; I saved another byte by turning it into a list comprehension (and thinking that this might be a very useful technique for other similar challenges).

Comment: Maybe there is a way to shorten the list comprehension, but a while loop still seems to be shorter: `while M:k=M[0]+M[-1];M=M[1:-1];A+=sorted(k+[i.pop(j)for j in[0,-1]for i in M]),` (174 bytes)

Comment: @ovs: You have omitted `,A=()` from your byte count...

Comment: I get [174 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoMgFAB3v@KNEGmjjloGPoDJkTA0FSuoQKhNtU376xQ7drtLLue3ZXC2irFTPVwRJ4wKiesMHoOeFPB6pFwUMufiUMqGJynrnVhOby4sqkNjLvTRO48M7l0AA9qKgqRmN50MuMQkg5a@LrNHqzCSbOJj5C9fybYnT@0RIyzN5d/l3QS13IOFSVnU4lN1th20MX4B) with `A=()`

Comment: Ah! Apologies, I misunderstood. This is different than your earlier version, which was of the form: `while M: A+= (some expression)`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>247</s> <s>232</s> 220 bytes

```java
x->{int i=0,j=x.length,k,m,M,p=0,P=0,r=0;for(;i<j;){for(M=m=x[k=i][--j];k<=j;)for(int q:new int[]{x[i][k],x[j][k],x[k][i],x[k++][j]}){m=m<q?m:q;M=M<q?q:M;}r=i++>0?(k=P<m?3:p>M?1:P==m?2:4)*r!=r*r?4:k:0;p=m;P=M;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVbfj6IwEH5e/4rePsGKhlZAAbvmXu7NxGQfCQ@s4i7yQ0X0uBD@dq9Tq@jqbbZuLikyDJ1vOh9fpy6CXdBZzOL9avuaRFM0TYLNBo2DKENV6yHKijCfB9MQ/YJHeEZzhf16vueXqtt6qFuth00RFCz0F5ojui87zxVMi6iuLWjZTcLsrXjXYi3VxtqKOSfsyqnuzpe54kbDhatWYI5pSksvppHvdToL342HlL2CN4C2drLwN@KJq9Jjc2JfK72FuMc@c8G93faZs1arlKbD9Sh11u6Yjpm1dsZundOo3X7WR0pMJ8N01HNWz@MRdiaUpiPiGOpT/oPmT/nIcGJHd1c0dScUwsJim2cod@u9y6oVRImid8tohlJGl/JS5FH25vkoyN82Kqfr5c@mCNPuclt0V@xlkWTK488kQZv35TaZodcQTZfZNNiFSMGq8wh83oqZd@fKqXyWoKp6GoJRawhM3JjcW6tfRyI8xoBwkyNZYPY1NNCQLYWEbQZlMCyTr4VZmIFjDo1hlfySgoSVNetjJrkoFnPH8Z2YLJWABbCqLR7Zb3BIA2yekjJKhKN3nMQrtc8wTKnsjOVmCNqt4zhzmB8dlzPOMP6d/YPu5klQIIVIiQ5zHjD/ntempOhgQPgNUwZpwIXKP8wNU0q@RAfFHn54YZ87pLAh5nRxLHmPTEKTi6YZQrj/1/dl8bGmtwtLpPRk5UeE5gjXPxHyI7Lyu1Qv@YaQr3te3zrvedY9Le@yuRuird16uqfhYxsKtvkO4b3eYEaPADCsn9j82wK9MLEHvkGTnEDjkzxhbEYrJOkL4Rj9Y0ITauFaNwfHhH1DdF770GIhoY2/Lq40KsMZUow7tNUTJ4AJRx8zLb7mgfxWB6IOmtJ1TjRHJoeKsH3nVhabzhAnzenJutqQ31PcGRmnk@5biiMHSjD8wbAOnZRZA3E1HiyuxtNE3d39Lli7Is74ZMYVn3Wr3v8F)

Outputs:

- `1` for "concave"
- `2` for "flat"
- `3` for "convex"
- `4` for "mixed"

Ungolfed:

```java
x -> { // lambda that takes in the input int[][]
  int i = 0, // index of right bound of ring
      j = x.length, // index of left bound of ring
      k, // index of row-column-pair in ring
      m, // minimum of ring
      M, // maximum of ring
      p = 0, // minimum of previous ring
      P = 0, // maximum of previous ring
      r = 0; // result
  for (; i < j; ) { // iterate the rings from outside inwards
    // set both min and max to be to top right corner of the ring (and sneakily set some loop variables to save space)
    for (M = m = x[k = i][--j]; k <= j; ) // iterate the row-column pairs of the ring from top-right to bottom-left
      for (int q : new int[] {x[i][k], x[j][k], x[k][i], x[k++][j]}) { // iterate all of the cells at this row-column pair (and sneakily increment the loop variable k)
        // find new minimum and maximum
        m = m < q ? m : q;
        M = M < q ? q : M;
      }
    r = // set the result to be...
      i++ > 0 ? // if this is not the first ring... (and sneakily increment the loop variable i)
              // if the new result does not match the old result...
              (k = P < m ? // recycling k here as a temp variable to store the new result, computing the result by comparing the old and new mins/maxes
                         3
                         : p > M ?
                                 1
                                 : P == m ? 
                                          2
                                          : 4) * r != r * r ? // multiplying by r here when comparing because we want to avoid treating the case where r = 0 (unset) as if r is different from k
                                                            4 // set the result to "mixed"
                                                            : k // otherwise set the result to the new result
              : 0; // if this is the first ring just set the result to 0
    // set the old ring mins/maxes to be the current ones
    p = m; 
    P = M;
  }
  return r; // return the result
}
```

Comment: [217 bytes](https://ideone.com/XolYt6)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>100</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```
{$[1=#?,/a:(,/x)@.=i&|i:&/!2##x;;(&/m>1_M,0)-&/(m:&/'a)>-1_0,M:|/'a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVP/atswEP6/T3EjI7Mhni1Zki0f7fYCfYISWtMmJbRJoYTisnavnn36ZZuOwmCconzS3Xe6X34oDveH02nb/fp6Jc4XP1Zl32Wrcsh/fj/fLd923bL8IheLgTlblvsLcX25qvJiWWZ7aL71@UUhrqvVZfeGw/r9dHR@Xn8/d1sa@ObpgbObbb975IFf@Tlfv5@Vt0@H2/5lc3a8ymqCcE3C75CcxdopJA6KNRSGG2rJJoWwVCtSmrELSUKxAN2tZAGiJyuS0a8AcmevSWaKNBlcNF4hvYkOFGqBan@r2UY7nYgNRUFgxktAekTpLoonltvH/ugTwAuCZ3vOXRdzhvBsHzUtKtDybB81QlYUf/wJnmxxjIv/AY88TaPwf@Dgz3X/ZTOESqDayNQgX49zLmKTY3XkVKPi7/Y3Jrbf@O4Xqf1pqJRr9@w/DtjoCd4timlYtVRLWMGntKwRD3Q1Tq1nSwzCxJNWEAgNklNN4Gn4r1i3gdfgBlOD2QHPxtDL/W7Y3KWsa3bTZxlj4npZje3BY8i4qhBWzdI5ETbpp5K6hMK/mUqczKb8w0thjmf5x9fct0MCX5hhh1u/AhZ@BRxtPgQxhjEFoj7czcI6/QE)

returns `1`=concave, `::`=flat, `-1`=convex, `0`=mixed

(`::` is used as a placeholder for missing values in k)

Comment: A different strategy, using oK: ```&/1_`{&/+(y>|/x;y<&/x;,/x=/:y)}':(,/*:'(|+:)\)'-1_(-1_1_+-1_1_)\```

Comment: @zgrep nice! :) feel free to post as a separate answer and take ideas from mine if you want - for instance it seems my splitting into rings is shorter, but I haven't tried it in oK yet

Comment: yes, [my ring-split works works in oK](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWkNHv0LTQc82U60m00pNX9FIWbmi9n@ahomCqYKZgomCubWJgrGCERCaWJsCSUMgzwLIMgaLmlpbQtWZav4HAA)

Comment: Ooh, that's a very neat ring split! I like it.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 168 bytes

Returns:

- `-1` for flat
- `0` for mixed
- `1` for convex
- `2` for concave

```javascript
f=(a,k=w=~-a.length/2,p,P,i,m,M,y=w)=>k<0?i%4%3-!i:a.map(r=>r.map(v=>Y|(X=k*k-x*x--)<0&&X|Y<0||(m=v>m?m:v,M=v<M?M:v),x=w,Y=k*k-y*y--))|f(a,k-1,m,M,i|M-m<<2|2*(M<p)|m>P)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVNb@IwEL3vr2APLQlyaOx80xgOK@0tUo9FVQ8RDd0sBBBFAaRo/zrrmRiSNA5lDyvZaDKeeTP2mxl@x3n8Mdumm52xWr8lp9OcazFZ8D3/Y8TDZbJ63/16YGRDnkhKMhKRI9/rfLwIzUl6Z99Zxvd0FA@zeKNt@XiLQs7H00J75ovBwjgMDoahh@b9/XMxDc2i0DKej7NJNspJxPMwmkSjXCcHvidTdDgOjsJBL@aQhUExZFpERhaGrGADLQo3epGNn/TTbL36WC@T4XL9rvV/rFezOE/6@uO3un6uvbxYpAfrlfRApJWI2lddb3kwPLPBzEEPF0SP9HzSC5QeNBAutvBxEFtIVIBQhKAQFbfSFSJV8YTIGklSVJzPpLESSByIbF208Cp7VgE4F3BxFamwzkaYeVDDcJRRxCtUSz6Le141hfNZ0bSoYUCURpj@z2W8UzFJMXmKj9oWO5iEBWYKUeXhI8v4OgpRyT0zge7yBxO6rlBiwNllo8@/a1TADjJRLcn6/9W1GRXtmSeHDk6ZJJJhhTDJKevitEk9u6EK2t3pufXudK81Z3N82LIBVV/XRgoNINEAywiniS0EiwEA5MMCfEi4PhhaoPOrIAxatGNWBeLaAOZJNmzvDOxAblgojn8G9mw5C4Ky6QE4oArGovSQvHUTZskB48BEFKKLCfjdxQ23KIkyTXwFRGBlGjT4onhlmdlyMF2@3FYJ3kZj7RKXAXgTjay8CoX/BbfsbSH5clcaKnelqby@7NPGbVsXtq9YNN/h9Bc)

### How?

#### Minimum and maximum on each ring

We compute the minimum **m** and the maximum **M** on each ring.

We test whether a cell is located on a given ring by computing the squared distance from the center of the matrix on each axis. Taking the absolute value would work just as well, but squaring is shorter.

A cell at **(x, y)** is located on the **n**-th ring (0-indexed, starting from the outermost one) if the following formula is *false*:

```
((Y != 0) or (X < 0)) and ((X != 0) or (Y < 0))
```

where:

- **X = k² - (x - w)²**
- **Y = k² - (y - w)²**
- **w = (a.length - 1) / 2**
- **k = w - n**

**Example:** is the cell **(1, 2)** on the 2nd ring of a 6x6 matrix?

```
  | 0 1 2 3 4 5   w = (6 - 1) / 2 = 2.5
--+------------   (x, y) --> ( x-w,  y-w) --> ((x-w)²,(y-w)²)
0 | 0 0 0 0 0 0   (1, 2) --> (-1.5, -0.5) --> (  2.25,   0.5)
1 | 0 1 1 1 1 0   
2 | 0[1]0 0 1 0   k = w - 1 = 1.5
3 | 0 1 0 0 1 0   k² = 2.25
4 | 0 1 1 1 1 0   X = 2.25 - 2.25 = 0 / Y = 2.25 - 0.5 = 1.75
5 | 0 0 0 0 0 0   ((X != 0) or (Y < 0)) is false, so (1,2) is on the ring
```

#### Flags

At the end of each iteration, we compare **m** and **M** against the minimum **p** and the maximum **P** of the previous ring and update the flag variable **i** accordingly:

- `i |= 1` if **m > P**
- `i |= 2` if **M < p**
- we set higher bits of **i** if **M != m**

At the end of the process, we convert the final value of **i** as follows:

```javascript
i % 4  // isolate the 2 least significant bits (for convex and concave)
% 3    // convert 3 to 0 (for mixed)
- !i   // subtract 1 if i = 0 (for flat)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
ŒDŒH€ẎUÐeZ_þƝṠFf/
```

Returns **1** for *concave*, **0** for *flat*, **-1** for *convex*, and nothing for *mixed*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVSxTsQwDN3vK/oBlTi7SdrsCCExM0B1YjoGdD/AysKG0O1IfAA/AAPL6fiP40eK7TpN0vaQGDglJ8exX@xnu3frzea@6/bb0/32/Pvh7fDxdLl7Xl/f7D6/Xg7vr2e3J93ukS5oXdC@6rqWflVZ8FqVBYsQRdGuykVRtC3K0fCNFSPHYl0WTVn4YASerAyZWUEgCcgPxAsYW3awZryISiJmr4Mowp0aB1@SKQwnyjqaYPSxAx7FqIoqGEl8PsGwAZgyiktTdGElCjtW5BYJBiMvCLkFCQeEjKkYeebFNzOiGjVCu2Q1I4Zi4JL57//kpd8VwY2Pwxazv2sUywpPcWkZ/leX8o1KMkpxUPnGhO@8EjhflGlf1y7tazdq63yijLbu3Gk0ZeA5Ai@FlAEzJFTIPvwqesmYU2HDinVNxEVu7jixnlJg/1qZMnXAshyB1M02Aas2Oji@nxDG8jBms9JZszz1JDqBb7Lm4Uh6FpdLyUScsMcFP20OLaPRSRxOblLioxwn0Q1Dfoxj7GME/o65fg5IanRHDeiOmug11@BZGpNMzC8WWfeufgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [oK](https://github.com/johnearnest/ok), 56 bytes

```
&/1_`{&/+(y>|/x;y<&/x;,/x=/:y)}':{(,/x)@.=i&|i:&/!2##x}@
```

Based off of [ngn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165942/42775).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLbbsIwDH3fV3hCKq12aXNtgreJP9mekBAPewUB396dOCmESZOmTU7dE8d2bJ/snj5307RZNb16/zg2/UN7eDv1ez68NNCP/f61Xx2683J1bLHp1s@v2@a0hfu9Xiz25/W0WbatJUeeLI1syZCGWHbQCrsAZMTqOBY/1921yWbYJB8WDJvGP0Uq8jxSoAibimQsWcfQCiktKwSlJUmshNh8maTTspcTePyltJGKoAgvkpG7oNlWJJWJjIorLe1AuNKwBbQVuNIpVg9UPv4BJy@AsvgXGBGOLsL/wNIdJoYePDoRXHWsq45rskZfyPIzVzPlNnFT/Wf6VUSuiKF4toGMxjny6MgO9@LMYBckToM0eTBREVxHFGzHHOGQc2AXcsQIC7gFw4iIqrRiOD2LyCAxE4CBISn6GAZcb1inEBWvM8Q8UrX576/zuekrp84v6qav9GxJ4V17TjjIyljJyrj41MyVe68322@2uY5u@gI)

```
concave:1 0 0
   flat:0 0 1
 convex:0 1 0
  mixed:0 0 0
```

Comment: no need for @ if you turn everything into one big lambda: `{&/1_\`{&/+(y>|/x;y<&/x;,/x=/:y)}':(,/x)@.=i&|i:&/!2##x}`

Answer (score 1):

## [C++17 (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 411 bytes

```cpp
#import<map>
#define R return
#define T(f,s)X p,c;for(auto&e:r){c=e.second;if(p.a&&!p.f(c)){s;}p=c;}R
using I=int;struct X{I a=0;I z=0;I f(I n){R!a||n<a?a=n:0,n>z?z=n:0;}I
l(X x){R z<x.a;}I g(X x){R a>x.z;}I e(X x){R a==z&a==x.a&z==x.z;}};I
N(I i,I j,I s){i*=s-i;j*=s-j;R i<j?i:j;}auto C=[](auto&&m){I
s=size(m),i=-1,j;std::map<I,X>r;for(;++i<s;)for(j=-1;++j<s;)r[N(i,j,s-1)].f(m[i][j]);T(g,T(l,T(e,R 0)3)2)1;};
```

A new high score! (at the time of posting, at least) Oh well, it's a bit nifty, but still C++.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVVRj6JIEH7nV9TOJAZu0AiKCg3Owz75sPtg5mESz1xYbLzmBAzgrNHlr69X3aAooJN7ONONRfVX1V9VdTXedttde97p9MzCbZxkduhup9LzivosojCHhGa7JLoo3mRfTZV32Koe8eNEdndZ3KFWohw9h/ZS6sXRijBf3vbcTufLtufLnqIcU5JvHY/kc2mXsmgNM4dFGUmzZOdl8H6cgev0yQwO4unLM4iU4/yL@@tXZLuvrhNZfTWaHl4PXCL5TNrI77BHCBzsfc9FDazPGne67x24hl40jnPo4AORnQP/w@WczKTvuA9TZxDgTJUj@8NJu4wE/C8gc2B28MqsgOQ8RPjqLJZFsJ1QOc6k1EnZgcqhojKnq6kBBrOyLMydPVPfp4nIDXl5YXZKFC4HiML3gL8ni@8yUwM17WrKEjMULthyESwV8iav1Td5g5Oqc@grA0VXNJKTk/TMIm@zW1GwP6iXxcn0SsNiTCR1w2mZ3G@O4FIA7WsZkz6dEukjZivYJvgmY7nSDL51IFSkowT4E3gv3mVg2/C0eCJC@yOON@CzJM3@SuKf4ACWjhZLGB0UmQG@ZKErKFzxH/NBvtgplQvHdzcpJUDxWdtThXLT@3RqlOiGhjecbniBWLZAEKiY1ehxkHLl7xHBKxZNkty4Ws/vRLIsfeQtSV9a5wykP1nm/Q3yVzxoZ@6ei4Q0q2aDhfTcD/pn9ETgB56Gf0gF1lvAH3Tfih3Usf7GzVqR/ToyZHu6qkPx2nB3m6yOfa3jcimX8EBC6LJIPodanNHjcaACH7kKXNQqUWhzhdygdaEfcogh0CMujlWYqGA20JqJ8CHiDeETJQ0daMJc47uJ2TDjO1T7oKjfENOE4rxWghtOUIkMR2J1XGH1yti4OEb6pWJwBgnG5pUPo7EDRl2NMg2j87hSGHXFLeLKRyN/gp4m0tUUW2rDB4e0iHX0RNRMxN0iNpjofV684iFIPFY07Ln@MgX@v2vqTg2R22qUNfx/dS010svC6KKuelkjva1Gt2XUP6los3/Go@v@Gd1rn9umHpYt0vZ2r9E1k5MzxXEQPT5EYaBzY85DN0VyeLgcOOC6SbWBzpuo5fYwMUzuaFxmdzg@OzU4J1F0Y3J2Oh6WnWoWLcmdmtqdCgzKHjf4RYTiSOwyaT@JnGKR@X5fhCis9WIfzXxw0sozMSzvhMvbqHFePq/LFfHLvfNpXfSCvsav31HReChNyllptHJWmsrqYSPdRNgIcvgAUYs9P/328Au3Tk9d/EA53suLNv4X)

Lambda `C` takes a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and returns 1 for concave, 2 for convex, 3 for flat, or 0 for mixed.

A more legible version of the code, with descriptive identifiers, comments, `R`->`return` and `I`->`int` written out, etc.:

```cpp
#include <map>

// Abbreviation for golfing. Spelled out below.
#define R return

// Macro to test whether all pairs of consecutive Ranges in `rings`
// satisfy a condition.
// func: a member function of Range taking a second Range.
// stmts: a sequence of statements to execute if the condition is
//        not satisfied. The statements should always return.
//        May be missing the final semicolon.
// Expands to a statement, then the return keyword.
// The value after the macro will be returned if all pairs of Ranges
// satisfy the test.
#define TEST(func, stmts)                                     \
    Range prev, curr;                                         \
    for (auto& elem : rings) {                                \
        curr = elem.second;                                   \
        // The first time through, prev.a==0; skip the test.  \
        if (prev.a && !prev.func(curr))                       \
        { stmts; }                                            \
        prev = curr;                                          \
    }                                                         \
    return

// Abbreviation for golfing. Spelled out below.
using I = int;

// A range of positive integers.
// A default-constructed Range is "invalid" and has a==0 && z==0.
struct Range
{
    int a = 0;
    int z = 0;
    // Add a number to the range, initializing or expanding.
    // The return value is meaningless (but I is shorter than void for golfing).
    int add(int n) {
        return !a||n<a ? a=n : 0, n>z ? z=n : 0;
        /* That is:
        // If invalid or n less than previous min, set a.
        if (a==0 || n<a)
            a = n;
        // If invalid (z==0) or n greater than previous max, set z.
        if (n>z)
            z = n;
        return dummy_value;
        */
    }

    // Test if all numbers in this Range are strictly less than
    // all numbers in Range x.
    int less(Range x)
    { return z < x.a; }

    // Test if all numbers in this Range are strictly greater than
    // all numbers in Range x.
    int greater(Range x)
    { return a > x.z; }

    // Test if both this Range and x represent the same single number.
    int equal(Range x)
    { return a==z && a==x.a && z==x.z; }
};

// Given indices into a square matrix, returns a value which is
// constant on each ring and increases from the first ring toward the
// center.
// i, j: matrix indices
// max: maximum matrix index, so that 0<=i && i<=max && 0<=j && j<=max
int RingIndex(int i, int j, int max)
{
    // i*(max-i) is zero at the edges and increases toward max/2.0.
    i *= max - i;
    j *= max - j;
    // The minimum of these values determines the ring.
    return i < j ? i : j;
}

// Takes a container of containers of elements convertible to int.
// Must represent a square matrix with positive integer values.
// Argument-dependent lookup on the outer container must include
// namespace std, and both container types must have operator[] to
// get an element.  (So std::vector or std::array would work.)
// Returns:
//   1 for a concave matrix
//   2 for a convex matrix
//   3 for a flat matrix
//   0 for a mixed matrix
auto C /*Classify*/ = [](auto&& mat)
{
    int mat_size=size(mat), i=-1, j;
    std::map<int, Range> rings;

    // Populate rings with the range of values in each ring.
    for (; ++i<mat_size;)
        for (j=-1; ++j<mat_size;)
            rings[RingIndex(i, j, mat_size-1)].add(mat[i][j]);

    // Nested macros expand to
    // Range prev, curr; for ... if (...) {
    //   Range prev, curr; for ... if (...) {
    //     Range prev, curr; for ... if (...) {
    //       return 0;
    //     } return 3;
    //   } return 2;
    // } return 1
    // Note each scope declares its own prev and curr which hide
    // outer declarations.
    TEST(greater, TEST(less, TEST(equal, return 0) 3) 2) 1;
};
```

Comment: I don't think 'nifty' means what you think it means

Comment: [379 bytes](https://pastebin.com/fsZEmnGF)